# Incorrect generation of bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that doing all through Hyde and generating a page with 3 Bootstrap eventually some reason I get the Bootstrap 2

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~    4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'  
gem 'haml' 
gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'  
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS  
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', branch: 'bootstrap3'  
gem 'devise'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~    4.0.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails'  
gem 'turbolinks'  
gem 'jbuilder', '~>1.2' 

group :doc do   
  gem 'sdoc', require: false 
end
```

I used these instructions:

```
Installing the CSS stylesheets

If you don't need to customize the stylesheets using Less, the only gem you need is the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem:

**gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"** After running bundle install, run the generator:

**rails generate bootstrap:install static**
```

But this hasn't helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass', branch: '3'
```